# How to plot a point on the highest elevation of a raster on a polygon. QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, altitude

I have a shp with more than 1700 polygons on a elevation raster.

I need to plot a point that represents the highest altitude location within the polygons, and then export those points as a new shp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum altitude in polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201009/maximum-altitude-in-polygons)

Comment: Use zonal stats tool.

Comment: The question is not duplicate. The other question asks how to get max **value**, this asks how to get **point** with max value.

Answer (score 2):

I first thought of recommending an approach here [Extract highest point in raster and convert to point vector](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255882/extract-highest-point-in-raster-and-convert-to-point-vector), but the large number of your polygons (1700) gives another challenge, so let me suggest a three-steps way as below.

(1) Run SAGA `Raster values to points` tool (in *Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector <-> Raster*). Select your elevation raster layer (let's call it `elevation`) as Grids. You may of may not assign your polygon layer to `Polygons` option. This will give you an extracted point layer (`Shapes`).

(2) Start `Join attributes by location` tool. Select `Shapes` layer as the Target vector layer and polygon layer as Join vector layer. (Any predicate will do: e.g. intersects). This will return a `Joined layer` point shapefile which has polygon id (let's say `fid`) field added onto the `Shapes` layer.

(3) Start `Extract by expression` tool (in *Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector selection tools* if it is QGIS 2.18). Expression would be  `"elevation"  = maximum("elevation", group_by:= "fid")`. This will return a new point shapefile layer `Extracted(expression)` which is the highest point within each polygon.

Please note the above expression can extract multiple "highest" points if there are cells of the same highest elevation.

Comment: does not work. In the second step the following error appears: Feature (0) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.

Comment: @HeitorNóbrega You do have to fix the geometry of your polygon layer. Nothing works with bad data.

Comment: this worked great for me, thanks!