# Extracting the lowest point within a boundary using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am wondering if anyone has any good pointers on extracting the coordinates of the lowest point within a given boundary/buffer zone in QGIS.  I am able to use Join Attribute By Location (Summary) where I select the elevation cell as a minimum to get the lowest elevation within a region.  However, I can't figure out a way to get the easting and northing coordinate as well.  I have hundreds of points I am trying to extract so it's not feasible to go look through the initial point files and match the elevation with the coordinate.  Does anyone have any tips on how I can somehow extract a coordinate with the lowest elevation within a given boundary/radius?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the canvas to show us what the data look like?

Comment: So you have buffer polygons and a elevation raster?

Comment: I am trying to extract the lowest point from a point vector within each of the buffer zones shown in the photo above.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Actually I just found a solution!  Thanks for enquiring though.  I followed the last two steps from this post and used minimum in the expression instead of maximum and it worked great!  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294038/how-to-plot-a-point-on-the-highest-elevation-of-a-raster-on-a-polygon-qgis